# PHPCS Allow simple methods in one line

Tags: php, code-formatting, phpcodesniffer

I find the code

```
$ids = array_map(function ($entity) { return $entity->getId(); }, $entities);
```

much more readable than

```
$ids = array_map(function ($entity) { 
    return $entity->getId(); 
}, $entities);
```

However, the [PHPCS](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) forces me to use the second style, because the first one fails with the following for PSR-2 styles:

- `Squiz.Functions.MultiLineFunctionDeclaration.ContentAfterBrace` says that *Opening brace must be the last content on the line*
- `Squiz.WhiteSpace.ScopeClosingBrace.ContentBefore` says that *Closing brace must be on a line by itself*
- `Generic.Formatting.DisallowMultipleStatements.SameLine` says that *Each PHP statement must be on a line by itself*

While I generally agree with these checks in other places, in this case they are completely wrong.

Is there a rule that would say to PHPCS that it should allow *Simple methods in one line* just like PHPStorm does?

[image: Simple methods in one line in PHPStorm]

I know I can [ignore PHPCS checks in such places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039362/how-can-i-suppress-phpcs-warnings-using-comments) but I would prefer tackling this in a global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the above and are using PHP >= 8, you can do this instead:

```
$ids = array_map(fn ($entity) => $entity->getId(), $entities);
```

PHP CodeSniffer won't complain about that one.